# Which chapters of the anime show Sakura learning/using the Byakugou no jutsu?

Tags: naruto

I remember that when Tsunade's was teaching Sakura the technique that will allow her to break the three medic ninja rules she told her something like she would have to amass a great amount of chakra for three years.

It was shown as some sort of pool being filled and when this pool is filled she would be able to use the byakugou no jutsu (This was the name I found, i'm not sure if there is other).

Any hint would be much appreciated. Sorry for my English.

Comment: are you looking for the part in the book or in the tv show?

Comment: I dont think any part actually does, its just implied heavily that you need that Diamond on your forehead, which is the sign your chakra storage is complete in order to use it. It can be turned on and off, but im sure it is indeed a more complicated feat than just thinking on or off. Consitering Sakura was doing this ever since shortly after becoming Tsunades disciple, she probably learned the tricks to doing it sometime during that timeskip, which very little was shown

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko I'm interested in the TV Chapter, but if there's any info in the Manga I'd like to know in which chapter of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In *Naruto Shippuuden*, episode 408, *The cursed puppet(noroi no ningyou)* is the episode from 2 minute to 5 minute time period, where Tsunade teaches Sakura about byakugou no jutsu.

As commented by [Wondercricket](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/33822/which-chapters-of-the-anime-show-sakura-learning-using-the-byakugou-no-jutsu#comment60685_46550), [episode 408](http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/naruto-shippuden/cursed-puppet) is a filler.

Comment: [Episode 408](http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/naruto-shippuden/cursed-puppet) is indeed a filler episode